# Bigcommerce API Tracking Number Create PHP

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I am trying to update the tracking number of an order in Bigcommerce using the API. This is the code I am using:

```
//update BC of order status
$filter = array('status_id' => 2);
$order_status_update = BigCommerce::updateResource('/orders/' . 105, $filter);

$order = Bigcommerce::getOrder(105);
foreach($order->products as $shipment) 
{
    $filter = array(
        'order_address_id' => $shipment->order_address_id,
        'items'=> array(
            'order_product_id' => $shipment->product_id,
            'quantity' => $shipment->quantity
            ),
        'tracking_number' => 'tracking number'
        );
    $add_tracking = BigCommerce::createResource('/orders/105/shipments', $filter);
    var_dump($add_tracking);
}
```

I have followed the instructions from here:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders/shipments#list-shipments
[BigCommerce Uploading Tracking Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663111/bigcommerce-uploading-tracking-numbers)

But I can't seem to get it to work. Can someone help?

In advance, thanks for your help!

Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload for creating a shipment is invalid due to the items field needing to be formatted as an object array and the use of the product_id as opposed to the ID of the product within the order.

The code provided is attempting to create one shipment per product in the order, is this intended?  Ideally you would ship all items in one shipment, which is why the items field is meant to be an array of product objects.

Additionally, by creating a shipment for an order the order status will automatically change to "Shipped", so the first PUT request is unnecessary.

If you were trying to create a single shipment per order and are assuming no orders will have multiple addresses then this code should work.

```
$order = Bigcommerce::getOrder(105);

$filter = array(
    'order_address_id' => $order->shipping_addresses[0]->id,
    'tracking_number' => '123456'
);

foreach($order->products as $product) {
    $items[] = array(
        'order_product_id' => $product->id,
        'quantity' => $product->quantity
    );
}

$filter['items'] => $items;

$add_tracking = BigCommerce::createResource('/orders/105/shipments', $filter);
var_dump($add_tracking);
```

Comment: Edited to account for shipping_addresses resource returning an object array.

Comment: I just checked the code out and it works! Thank you very very very much. I have been stuck on this for over a month and you made me very happy, haha!

Comment: @adambil Would you know why I would receive a `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BigCommerce\Api\NetworkError' with message '<url> malformed'` when I use this code?